# Is it Possible to fetch a data from table_a to table_b? if yes please send suggestions or query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, double

I want to show notifications and name or image, who send friend request same as facebook.
I have two tables one is users [users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R21dv.png)where all users are registered, and

second one is friends [friends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fLvu.png)where friend request and all these stuff are mention.

I want to show the content from users table and check the condition in friend table.

Please give me suitable solution on this.

Comment: Which RDMS are you using, sql or mysql? If mysql, then here is the reference link to use `JOINS` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: It would help if you added the table definitions to your question as well as any attempts you've made so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to link the tables with the primary key/foreign key.
For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableUsers u JOIN TableFriends f ON u.UserId = f.UserId;
```

Now you have both tables linked and you can access both tables.